# How to get data from sql DB in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to get data from sql DB in selenium webdriver?

I would like to connect the selenium webdriver and sql DB, and need to get value from DB and to use in the selenium testNg framework. 
Can any one provide me the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make connection with database by using following commands,

DriverManager.getConnection(URL of database, "username", "password" )

To get value, use following commands

ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(select * from tablename;);

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement DB connector helper for connect, execute query and close data base connection. After than you can use result of query in your test.

Data Base connector depends on DB type(you need use specify DB driver). 
Folowing java methodis illustrated connection with SQL Server Driver:

```
 public java.sql.Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(SQLServerDriver.class.getName());
            con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl(), userName, password);
            if (con != null) System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return con;
    }
```

and execute query:

```
public void executeQuery(String query) {
        con = this.getConnection();
        if (con != null) {
            Statement st = null;
            try {
                st = con.createStatement();
                st.executeQuery(query);
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
        this.closeConnection();
    }
```

than close connection:

```
 public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
            con = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```